# ¿Por qué quinceañero, veinteañero y treintañero, pero cuarentón, cincuentón, etc?

Tags: etimología, historia, adjetivos

Para las personas de alrededor de 15 años se utiliza quinceañero; para las de 20 a 29 años, veinteañero y para las que tienen entre 30 y 39, treintañero.

Pero para las décadas siguientes las denominaciones pasan a ser cuarentón, cincuentón, sesentón, etc.

¿Por qué se produce ese cambio en la construcción de los grupos etarios, de "edad + añero" a "edad + -ón"?

Comment: Cuarentón, cincuentón y otros son sus formas coloquiales, habría que recurrir a informes históricos para entender sus razones y orígenes, puede tener connotaciones sexistas y descriminatorias. Lo correcto para una edad entre 40 y 49 sería cuadragenario (https://dle.rae.es/?w=cuadragenario)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me imagino que el cambio se da porque los términos para mayores edades son una especie de peyorativo y sentimiento de discriminación de edad. "Ah qué mal, ya soy cuarentón!" Esto refleja el sentimiento por lo menos de la sociedad urbana en Guatemala de acuerdo a mi experiencia de muchos años de vivir allí.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22688)

Comment: I'm not critiquing not requesting clarification and I don't know why you think I am.

Comment: @mdewey If you knew more about Spanish culture you would understand my answer. You should at least do some research at the question before trying to delete my answer just because you have a different culture.

Comment: It is the canned response the system inserts. The OP specifically asked "¿Por qué se produce ese cambio ...? and your response, interesting though it is, did not seem to answer that.

Comment: @mdewey Ok, I corrected the form of my answer

Comment: Concuerdo con @freethinker36  en que "cuarentón", "cincuentón", "sesentón" se usan en un contexto para indicar que se está en una edad a la que no aplica hacer o decir algo, similar a la implicación de decir "solterón".